# Why cv::gpu::GaussianBlur is slower, than cv::GaussianBlur?

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, gpu

I'm not a pro in C++, OpenCV and CUDA, and don't understand why

```
cv::gpu::warpPerspective(g_mask, g_frame, warp_matrix, g_frame.size(), 
    cv::INTER_LINEAR, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar(255,255,255));
cv::gpu::GaussianBlur(g_frame, g_frame, cv::Size(blur_radius, blur_radius), 0);
g_frame.download(mask);
```

is slower, than

```
cv::gpu::warpPerspective(g_mask, g_frame, warp_matrix, g_frame.size(), 
    cv::INTER_LINEAR, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar(255,255,255));
g_frame.download(mask);
cv::GaussianBlur(mask, mask, cv::Size(blur_radius, blur_radius), 0);
```

Tell me, why is this happening? Or i wrote wrong code?

Comment: Maybe some extra information on the size of the matrices you are applying the kernel to might be useful.

Comment: What is the model of your CPU and GPU?

Comment: @Max all Mat's are frames of video. Speed not depends on size. With lower resolution both functions work proportionally faster.

Comment: @sgar91 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz and Nvidia GeForce GT 630M

Comment: OpenCV GPU is slow, so this is not uncommon.

Comment: @accelereyes it's not fast on CPU either. I have only 7 fps on HD video with overlaying single image with perspective transformation. It is very slow. I need at least 25 fps for such simple operation. But i get only 19 fps for only reading image from source. Even without modifying and rendering! Maybe you can advise any other library in wich i can do perspective transformation on image and overlay it on video?

Comment: are you using opencv with IPP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Too Slow GpuMat uploading of an small image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454373/too-slow-gpumat-uploading-of-an-small-image)

Comment: @КонстантинВан It is a fairly old theme to answer to... But no, your link probably does not answer to my question, because uploading and downloading are not the case in my examples - in both snippets those actions are the same. There is a difference only in one function.
Need to mention, that I have not checked this theme and there are a lot changed. Almost all changed in 10 years, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

IPC overhead to the GPU is usually the culprit. You should consider using the cv::Stream interfaces to minimize that overhead.