# Too Slow GpuMat uploading of an small image

Tags: opencv, gpu

I want to upload an image into the following variable `gpu::GpuMat test;`. First of all the input image(src) is converted into a grayscale image `cvtColor( src, src_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );` and then it is uploaded `test.upload(src_gray);`. Unfortunately, it took so much time for the uploading. More than **two minutes**. The image size is 169x90. I know that that generally there is some delay because of the bandwidth but I think two minutes are too much for such a small image. Finally, I want to mention that after the uploading of the first image the up loading of the next images is almost instant. Is there any initialization procedures? Can we improve such delay?

```
int main( int, char** argv )
{
/// Load source image and convert it to gray
string filename =  argv[1] ;//"yourfile.avi";
VideoCapture capture(filename);
if( !capture.isOpened() )
    throw "Error when reading steam_avi";

int framenumber=1;
Mat src, src_gray;
gpu::GpuMat test;

namedWindow( "w", 1);
time_t start,end;
time (&start);
for( ; ; )
{
    //printf("Frame %d: \n", framenumber++ );
    capture >> src;

    cvtColor( src, src_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );

    test.upload(src_gray);//it takes too long even for an image of 169x90
    if( src_gray.empty() )
        break;
    imshow("w", src_gray);



    waitKey(20); // waits to display frame

}
time (&end);
double dif = difftime (end,start);
printf ("Elasped time is %.2lf seconds.", dif );
getchar();

return(0);
}
```

[image]

with **--memory=pageable** parameter.

PS: Win 7 64x, CUDA SDK 5.5, Opencv 2.4.6, GeForce 9600.

Comment: Why are you measuring the time of the whole video instead of a single frame? The timer is around the `for` loop instead of `test.upload(src_gray);`.

Comment: Ok the timer is placed there to count the entire time of the whole procedure. The code is placed there as an example. The **two minutes** of delay are referred only on the uploading time, e.i on the line `test.upload(src_gray);`. Thanks for the interest and sorry if I was unclear.

Answer (score 6):

The first call of any gpu function is slow due to CUDA context initialization. All next calls wil be faster. Call some gpu function before time measurement:

```
gpu::GpuMat test;
test.create(1, 1, CV_8U); // Just to initialize context
time(&start);
...
time(&end);
```

Comment: The fact that you initialize a very small matrix means that the first uploading will be fast? I test it and it consumes the same time to upload the data as previous. Is anything wrong or it is normal? Also I run the bandwidth test and I have noticed that the uploading rate is 1,8Gb/s. Based on that info the uploading shouldn't be quick? Does this delay has to do with my old graphic card? Anyhow, I found it very strange to take two minutes for initialization that is why I am insisting. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

CUDA context initialization at most take several secs, the over minutes delay is due to your opencv binary code not capable with your NVidia card. To solve this problem, you must rebuild your opencv libaray.

First, edit opencv/cmake/OpenCVDetecCUDA.cmake, find the line:

```
if(NOT DEFINED __cuda_arch_bin)
```

add following two lines before above line:

```
...
set(__cuda_arch_bin "3.5 5.0")
set(__cuda_arch_ptx "3.5 5.0")

if(NOT DEFINED __cuda_arch_bin)
...
```

Then, rebuild and reinstall your opencv:

```
cd opencv/build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_CUDA=ON -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 ..
make -j8
make install
```